# how to check if next record exists in an msi file?

Tags: c#, python, vbscript, wix, windows-installer

With MsiViewFetch we are able to get the record from the sql query to msi.
But is there any constant or function to check whether next record exists or number of rows/records in a file table msi?

Comment: You tagged this three different languages.  Which one do you want an answer for?

Answer (score 3):

No. Windows Installer's implementation of SQL is fairly limited. All that's available is the option to call [MsiViewFetch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370514) repeatedly until it returns **ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS**. Once you have retrieved all the records, it will do so. It is up to you to track the count along the way, and also properly handle all returned objects. (For example, each successfully returned record must be closed with [MsiCloseHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370067), and in unusual circumstances the view itself may need to be closed with [MsiViewClose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370510).)

As noted, this may be expressed differently in different languages that wrap it. For example, the Windows Installer Automation Interface's [View.Fetch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372509) method returns **Nothing** if you have already retrieved all the records. Cleaning up resources will typically have been altered to use the conventions of the language in question as well.

In particular, Python's msilib is a wrapper of Windows Installer functionality that was implemented specifically to support creating Python's own installers. Because it wasn't intended for general purpose use, it lacks some of the creature comforts of other wrappers. You can see that the [implementation of View.Fetch](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a935654f0613640535fbf0ba190f81d02a63d35c/PC/_msi.c#L720-L730) turns any non-success return code into an MSIError, and **ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS** is not **ERROR_SUCCESS**. So for your usage, you will have to catch MSIError and either hope it's for ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS, or check the exception's string for the **103** embedded within.

Comment: I tried with below code in python but it is failing.

Comment: Some languages such as C# have third party libraries that abstract this. Hence why I asked about languages.

Comment: This is the error I am getting.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/uday-/Documents/GitHub/InstallTesting/utiltities/reading msi/MSIFileRead.py", line 17, in <module>
    cur_record = view.Fetch()#https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372509(v=vs.85).aspx
_msi.MSIError: unknown error 103

Comment: And this is the code I am having.
https://bugs.python.org/file47271/MSIFileRead.py